# How do I use UINT64_MAX standard library macro?

Tags: c++, integer, c-standard-library

While learning C++ I recently came across the usage of macros and learnt that there are many standard macros such as this one (and many others for Integers) :

```
#include <cstdint>    
UINT64_MAX
```

*(from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)*

I don't really understand what it is even though the name speaks for itself (i guess?) and how to use it in a code.

***EDIT :***
I know this macro returns the max value that a *uint64_t* can contain. What I don't know is how and when this should be used. If you could give a written example and a "common" scenario, it would be perfect.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you don't understand about it? It's the maximum value a `std::uint64_t` can hold.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more precise. What I don't get is what would be the common usages for such a macro ? In which case scenarios oneself should be using this or another integer-type macro (UINT32_MIN, UINT16_MAX...) 
( I'm editing my post. )

Comment: Suppose you had a double and you wanted to know if it was valid to cast it to the nearest 64 bit integer without losing anything aside than  the fractional part.  .  You would need to verify that a) it's greater than or equal to zero and b) it's less than or equal to UINT64_MAX.   Probably better to use std::numeric_limits instead of the macro but either way the principle is the same.

Comment: Ok this example makes perfect sense, thank you.

Comment: In an embedded system, with custom memory mapped hardware, I  prefer to use < cstdint > definitions to clearly identify the access width identified by the hw requirements.  For example, the access width might match a std::UINT32_MAX, and have multiple smaller fields (that need masking and shifting to access).  The memory mapped register address and width might be declared as "std::UINT32_MAX* cntrl = 0xffcc0000;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***UINT64_MAX*** is used to return the maximum value a ***uint64_t*** can contain.
A common scenario would be to cast a double into a uint64_t. We would :

1. make sure that the uint64_t variable it is casted to is greater than
   or equal to zero.
2. it's less than or equal to UINT64_MAX (std::numeric_limits would apparently work too.)

Here is an example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
    constexpr double a = 6383464.632463948;

    if (b >= 0 && b <= UINT64_MAX) {
        uint64_t b = (uint64_t)a; // Cast the double into the uint64_t variable
        std::cout << "Conversion from double to uint64_t is valid" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "b value is " << b << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Conversion from double to uint64_t is not valid" << 
std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check if a >= 0 && a <= UINT64_MAX, then do the cast, not before.